# Fiddler - intercept request return different response

Tags: fiddler, jscript

In Fiddler I have some custom rules that upon getting a certain response from the server, it sends out a new request automatically:

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
    ...
    if (oSession.uriContains("something.aspx")) {

        var requestB = "..."
        FiddlerObject.utilIssueRequest(requestB);
    }
...
}
```

I want to intercept a requestA from the client, wait until I have received a response back for requestB, and then return requestB's response for requestA. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the function `FiddlerApplication.oProxy.SendRequestAndWait` like this:

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) 

{
...
    if (oSession.uriContains("something.aspx"))
   {
        var oSD = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary();
        var GetResquestBAnswer : Session = FiddlerApplication.oProxy.SendRequestAndWait(RequestB.oRequest.headers, RequestB.requestBodyBytes, oSD, null);
        if (200 == GetResquestBAnswer.responseCode)
        {
           oSession.ResponseBody=GetResquestBAnswer.ResponseBody;
        }
    } 
...
}
```